# How can you get the body content from a azure mobile services request.respond(statusCode, body)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, windows-store

I am using azure mobile services and I have the following code on the server:

```
  request.respond(statusCodes.OK, "success");
```

On my windows store app I have:

```
await App.MobileService.GetTable<UserEntity>().InsertAsync(App.CurrentUser);
```

How can I retrieve the body message?

Comment: What are you looking to do?  By default, InsertAsync's response content will be parsed into a UserEntity object.  Given you are returning a string, I'd expect you'd get an error when this code runs.

Comment: This code works perfectly, check documnentation....                          request.respond(statusCode, body)
Writes a custom response with the provided HTTP status code and message body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile services client, expects the response content from a table call to return JSON on success. It will attempt to deserialize the response into the requested object (UserEntity) and mutate the item you passed in if successful.

Since the string you are returning ("success") is probably not able to be deserialized into a UserEntity object, I'd expect the insertAsync() to throw an error on along the lines of "Newtonsoft reader, unexpected character encountered..."

If you update your request.respond() to return a valid json packet like { name: 'username', address: '123 Home' }, etc then your App.CurrentUser object would be updated to reflect those changes.

note: If you're not seeing the above error, double check that your call to request.respond() is in the request.execute() success callback. You may be trying to write to the response a second time, and that second time will fail (and should be visible in your app's logs)

Comment: We are talking about an insert so the result is void...the insertasync call return an exception if the statuscode is not 200. I don't have any errors and probably the you can't get the returned result because it is private...I have tried with { message : "success" } and no use...

Comment: Take a look at the reference guide for the REST API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj677200.aspx

If your UserEntity object has a message field, then I would expect that would say success. Do you have an example of the kind of data you actually want to return?  It would help get you a better answer with a concrete example.

Comment: Hy Philip, you are right, if I have a field in that matches the body from the request.respond it will update it.

Comment: Say I have the id property in my entity and I return  request.respond(statusCodes.OK, { id: 'success' }); The new value of id will be success.